# Abaqus dload function - passing data to

Tags: matlab, abaqus

I am attempting to model a fan disk from an EDF in Abaqus. The centrifugal loading for the part has been figured out, the hard part is the aerodynamic loading.

To do this, I figured it would be easier to figure out the loading outside of abaqus and apply it - I only need the FEA results, I dont want to take on a CFD project if I dont have to.

So, I wrote MATLAB code that produced a XFOIL instruction set. This did 100 analysis on individual 2d airdoils, with the proper free stream velocity, Reynolds number, and angle of attack for that section specifically. This was all put together into a matrix describing the pressures at all the points along the fan blade (required scaling and locating the data, as well as dimensionalizing cP into actual pressure values.) Copying the list and rotating about the disk origin gave me a 176000x4 matrix for all the blades containing the x,y,z coordinates with the 4th column being the pressure in Pa at that location.

Now, I need to use the dload subroutine to load this into Abaqus and I'm a little lost.

First, all the advice I find for dload have function controlled pressures, not a list. So, am I crazy for trying to pass a list of pressures into Abaqus? Is this not done?

Second, how do I actually go about writing a dload protocol and getting it into abaqus? I'm really stumped on how this actually works, some are saying it's a FORTRAN protocol and other people are telling me to use python. Help!

I tried making a matrix 176,000 data points... I expected a option to pass a list of pressures to the model. I was kinda stuck when that wasn't an easy option.